# Looping through equations

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop

Is there a way to loop through these calculations and input them into a dataframe as the indicated variable instead of having to calculate them individually. I know repetition is a no-no, but I am not sure how else to do this.

The values of P are constants for different minerals (e.g., P_Cpx, P_Pl) and the D values are constants for different elements and the corresponding mineral (e.g., D_Nb_Cpx).

```
D_Th_bulk = (P_Cpx * D_Th_Cpx) + (P_Pl * D_Th_Pl) + (P_Opx * D_Th_Opx) + (P_Ol * D_Th_Ol) + (P_Mt * D_Th_Mt) + (P_Ilm * D_Th_Ilm) + (P_Ap * D_Th_Ap) + (P_Chr * D_Th_Chr) + (P_Maj_gn * D_Th_Maj_gn) + (P_Amp * D_Th_Amp)
D_Nb_bulk = (P_Cpx * D_Nb_Cpx) + (P_Pl * D_Nb_Pl) + (P_Opx * D_Nb_Opx) + (P_Ol * D_Nb_Ol) + (P_Mt * D_Nb_Mt) + (P_Ilm * D_Nb_Ilm) + (P_Ap * D_Nb_Ap) + (P_Chr * D_Nb_Chr) + (P_Maj_gn * D_Nb_Maj_gn) + (P_Amp * D_Nb_Amp)
D_La_bulk = (P_Cpx * D_La_Cpx) + (P_Pl * D_La_Pl) + (P_Opx * D_La_Opx) + (P_Ol * D_La_Ol) + (P_Mt * D_La_Mt) + (P_Ilm * D_La_Ilm) + (P_Ap * D_La_Ap) + (P_Chr * D_La_Chr) + (P_Maj_gn * D_La_Maj_gn) + (P_Amp * D_La_Amp)
D_Ce_bulk = (P_Cpx * D_Ce_Cpx) + (P_Pl * D_Ce_Pl) + (P_Opx * D_Ce_Opx) + (P_Ol * D_Ce_Ol) + (P_Mt * D_Ce_Mt) + (P_Ilm * D_Ce_Ilm) + (P_Ap * D_Ce_Ap) + (P_Chr * D_Ce_Chr) + (P_Maj_gn * D_Ce_Maj_gn) + (P_Amp * D_Ce_Amp)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can write a loop with a `for` statement, have you tried that?

Comment: Hi mkrieger, could you point me in the right direction of how I would go about this? I know how for loops work in general, but this seems a little above my knowledge (I'm still learning the ins and outs of Python).